# How to overcome ZF2 session start in console request

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I am running a ZF2 action from terminal using console route.
The running user is not Apache and the request is not an http request. The application throws an error that it has no permission to write the session file.

Is there any way to avoid session while I am using a console route?

Comment: What are using for OS and HTTP server? Seems to be a folder permission issue.

Comment: its linux os and apache server.

Comment: Have you tried this http://serverfault.com/questions/70634/what-permissions-ownership-to-set-on-php-sessions-folder-when-running-fastcgi It seems to be a folder write permission issue

Comment: This may solve the problem. But the server is not under my control. Can we do any change in zf2?

Answer (score 2):

Console requests and http requests can be distinguished from eachother by the request class. You can use this to recognize the request type and disable or enable certain functionality in your application:

You can easily use this in your `module.php` file for example in a bootstrap method. I will use the session example [from the ZF2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.manager.html) to show how this could work:

```
<?php
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Http\Request as HttpRequest;
use Zend\Console\Request as ConsoleRequest;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;
use Zend\Session\Container;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $eventManager        = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

        $this->bootstrapSession($event);
    }

    public function bootstrapSession(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if($request instanceof ConsoleRequest){
            // nothing to do
            return
        }

        $session = $event->getApplication()
                         ->getServiceManager()
                         ->get('Zend\Session\SessionManager');
        $session->start();

        //... remaining code for session
    }
}
```

You can think of any other variant of course:

```
if(! $request instanceof HttpRequest){
    return;
}

if($request instanceof ConsoleRequest){
    //.. do something
}elseif($request instanceof HttpRequest){
    //.. do something else
}
```